# Connecting Blackberry JDE with a php based server

Tags: php, blackberry

I am new to blackberry application development.I am using Blackberry Eclipse... I am trying to connect blackberry JDE with an PHP based server.I have read many forums which says use of KSOAP ...

I want to know that after installing KSOAP...where should i write php codings?

PLEASE HELP...

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean by "php codings"

kSOAP is (AFAIK) just a lightweight SOAP implementation for java. It composites and decodes the requests as SOAP calls which can then be sent to a webservice which can be implemented in any language. From the webservice point of view, it doesn't really matter what the client is doing as long as it is talking SOAP.

There is a SOAP implementation as standard in recent builds of PHP. Which is [well documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) but if you've got an older version or for some reason it has not been included in your install (and you can't fix that) there is also a pure [php implementation - nuSOAP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/)

Comment: hi symcbean...
thnkxxx for replyimg...
i am not getting how to call those services...
i do have got some services like system.connect from an server which would respond to some phases of my application...
but i am not getting how to make it work...
could you please help in it....

Comment: You seem very confused - you never connect **from** a server - only ever **to** a server - otherwise its not a server. There's lots of docs out on the internet - e.g. http://devzone.zend.com/article/689 try google for more